# Декодирование windows-1251 (cp1251) с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, кодировка, перекодировка, cp1251

Столкнулся с проблемой, к сожалению, корректного решения не нашёл: задача в том, чтобы с помощью Яваскрипта декодировать фрагмент url, закодированный в windows-1251 (cp1251).

Знаю, что существуют методы **decodeURI()** и **decodeURIComponent()**, но они, насколько я понял, работают только с UTF-8. Решение, которое я находил, использует устаревшие методы escape() и unescape() в связке с предыдущими.

Например, есть последовательность:

**%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5** (программирование)

Методы decodeURI() и decodeURIComponent() вызовут исключение.

Буду благодарен за помощь или подсказку, в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: По-моему `escape` и `unescape` никто не отменял.

Comment: @nick_n_a эти методы обозначены как устаревшие, в любой момент поддержка может прекратиться https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

И они применимы только к UTF-8

Comment: Вот же в мозилле есть `alert(decodeURI("https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B"));`  [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) у меня работает, может стоит добавить  `y= (decodeURI)?decodeURI(x) : unescape(x);`

Comment: В UTF-8 записал - то же работает. Набросайте минимальный html с функцией  decodeURI где у вас ошибка.

Comment: @nick_n_a decodeURI не работают с кодировкой cp1251, попробуйте вызвать в Файерфоксе alert(decodeURI("%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5"))
Это вызовет ошибку, поскольку последовательность закодирована cp1251. Если же вызвать unescape("%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5"), то, в случае, если на странице не кодировка cp1251, будет видно вот это "ïðîãðàììèðîâàíèå"

Comment: @nick_n_a нашёл решение, чуть позже опубликую

Comment: А не припомните решение данной проблемы? А то написано, что опубликуете, но видимо забыли :(

Comment: @РоманДанилов к сожалению, до сих пор руки не дошли опубликовать ответ) В общем, это процентное кодирование и есть 2 пути: я задавал на англ. версии вопрос, там предлагали через TextDecoder (экспериментальная технология) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41451528/6398233


А я нашёл вариант преобразования через карты символов на http://www.codenet.ru/services/urlencode-urldecode/. Автор ресурса сообщил, что не против, если я опубликую со ссылкой на оригинал. В общем, в разметке можно посмотреть, там скрипт с кодом, можно по имени ф-ии найти convert_to_cp1251